# How to access json object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am not an expert in json parsing so please bear with me if i ask simple question.I have a json response like this :

```
{
    "resp": [{
        "Key": "123423544235343211421412",
        "id": "12"
    }]
}
```

I want to access value of key and id (123423544235343211421412,12)
.I tried following but i can't get the values!

I appreciate if you guys show me how to get those values.Thanks

```
var postData = {
    Name: "Galaxy",
    action: "token"
};  

$.ajax("https://someapiurl/getit.aspx",{
    type : 'POST',      
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    contentType: "application/json",    
    success: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(json.resp[0].Key); 
        alert(json.resp[1].id);  
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: I believe with jquery.ajax, a) you don't need to JSON.stringify the input data, and you don't need to JSON.parse the success data with the contentType/dataType you have set in the function call ... i.e. you should pass in a plain ol' js object, and you will receive a plain ol' js object

Comment: alert(data.resp[0].Key);

Comment: you can alert(JSON.stringify(data)) to show the data in a string.  also for your second alert, it should be json.resp[0].id because you're only showing one object in the array

Comment: @JaromandaX your first point is not correct. In order to send a JSON request body, you need to do what OP is doing. Your second point however is correct and is probably the cause of OP's problem

Comment: On second thought, i guess it depends on what the response is.

Comment: @Phil - I disagree - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the data property - though on re-reading the documentation myself I'm now less sure of myself :p

Comment: @JaromandaX the default jQuery action is to convert the object to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. OP appears to be posting JSON

Comment: @Phil - agreed :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. jQuery automatically parses the response as JSON for you when you specify `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax('https://someapiurl/getit.aspx', {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData)
}).done(function(obj) {
    alert(obj.resp[0].Key);
    alert(obj.resp[0].id);
})
```

Comment: Thanks all for replies. Phil your answer fixed the problem !Thanks

Comment: afaik you can omit the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',` and the `JSON.stringify` in the request part as well. `dataType: 'json',` will do those for you as well

Comment: @OlleKelderman no it won't. `dataType` is specifically relating to the **response** whereas if you want to send a JSON formatted **request** body instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you need to provide a `data` string and set the appropriate `contentType`.